# Vagrant host synced folder is empty

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have used vagrant and virtual box. I make a syncfolder for shared file between host and guest. I see shared folder in virtual box and I put some files in it but when I check the shared folder in host I see this folder is empty I have used the following command for making synced folders:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/home/jody/Desktop/MYSHARE", "/home/vagrant/share",owner:"vagrant"
```

What is the problem?

Comment: does it work the other way ? files from host are visible after you `vagrant up` the VM ?

Comment: with vagrant up I see that file.

Comment: but in other direction I have problem yet

Comment: maybe it is set to `rsync`, create a file in host and run `vagrant rsync` see if the file is visible from VM

Comment: Thanks For your suggestions. Actually the problem was virtual machine UI. When I start copy file on both direction in terminal I got no error and finally see guest machine file in shared folder. but the virtual machine UI do not show shared file yet.Thanks again. :)

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618103/why-is-the-default-vagrant-shared-folder-empty